# Change data value of object tag on button press

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object tag with a blank data value and a menu of hyperlinks. I need the data value of the object tag to change to the href link set in each menu item upon click, preferably using javascript.

All help appreciated and thank you in advance.

**EDIT**:
Lets say i have an object tag with data="" If Link A has `a href="this.html"` I want the data attribute of object to become `data="this.html"` when Link A is clicked

Comment: Why are you using an `<object>` as a pseudo-iframe? Just use a real `<iframe>`, then you can use regular links with `target` attributes. Better yet - just use normal links that reload the whole page and use a server side template for the shared content (that way bookmarking and linking will work).

Comment: i'm building a webapp and iOS can have problems with iframes. Don't want the whole page to reload either, so I'm doing it the best way possible for what I need to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On clicking the Anchors link the object data gets changed ,hoping this is what you want

```
  <html>
        <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>    
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

        $("a").click(function() {

        var thisObjectText=$(this).attr("href");
        if(thisObjectText!=null && thisObjectText!="")
        {
        $('#swf').attr("data",thisObjectText);
        alert($('#swf').attr("data"));
        }


        });

        });



        </script>
        </head>
        <body>

        <div id="test">
        <a href="#first" name="test-1">Aaaa</a>
        <a href="#second" name="test-2">Baaa</a>
        <a href="#third" name="test-3">Caaa</a>
        <a href="#fourth" name="test-4">Daaa</a>
        </div>


        <object id="swf" width="400" height="400" data=""></object> 
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Try this snippet, it fetches the link from anchor tag and place in data attribute of object tag

Comment: Had to change it to pull a value from the anchor tag to prevent the actual page from changing but the code works perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

By going through your question what i analyzed is you have anchor tags on clicking those anchor tag " the value attached to that tag should pass to the objects"

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("a").click(function() {

var obj=new Object;
obj={};

var thisObjectText=$(this).attr("name");

obj.value=thisObjectText;

alert("object value on clicking links " + obj.value);

});

});



</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="test">
<a href="#" name="test-1">Aaaa</a>
<a href="#" name="test-2">Baaa</a>
<a href="#" name="test-3">Caaa</a>
<a href="#" name="test-4">Daaa</a>
</div>
<div id="result">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to have jquery.js inside your folder

Comment: You misundersstood.

Lets say i have an object tag with data=""

If Link A has a href="this.html" I want the data attribute of object to become data="this.html" when Link A is clicked.